# How to include an image as a superscript

Tags: graphics, superscripts

A publisher requires authors to specify the corresponding author by placing an image next to the corresponding author:

> Please place an envelope icon (or any other pointer) next to the name
>   of the corresponding author

I want to add the image as a superscript. How to do this in Latex?

Answer (score 7):

Using the [`fontawesome`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) icon set:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
Test\textsuperscript{\faEnvelopeO}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

With [`marvosym`](https://ctan.org/pkg/marvosym):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\begin{document}
Test\textsuperscript{\Letter}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot2]

Though there are many other symbol packages containing such an envelope icon.

Comment: I am using WinShell (in Windows). I get this error when I try to produce the PDF document (F10) `Error: pdflatex.exe (file FontAwesome--fontawesometwo): Font FontAwesome--fontawesometwo at 420 not found`

Comment: @None Googling WinShell reveals that it doesn't include a LaTeX distribution. The package `fontawesome` might be missing.

Answer (score 2):

You can choose the code below. With `[scale=0.04]` you can increase or decrease the size of image as superscript. You could insert any image instead of `example-image-b`. The one you like best. You could also choose any format of picture .pdf, .jpg, .tiff, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
An example of an image as a text superscript\textsuperscript{\includegraphics[scale=0.04]{example-image-b}}.\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would strongly advise not to typeset regular text in math mode (or even inside `\mathrm{}`). If you want to use `^` in math mode, at least enclose the text inside a `\text{}` (with the `amsmath` package) or use the `\textsuperscript{}` without math mode like in my answer.

Comment: Accept your suggestion. I have edited my code.

Comment: Please remove the space before the superscript and add a screenshot again. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, it compiles correctly (F5, F6, F5, F5) but when it comes to produce the PDF (F10) I get an error `there was an error opening this document. This file cannot be found`. I am using Windows and WinShell as a text editor. I am sure I use the right path and image file name. I placed a `.eps` version of the image in the specified folder. I already have another image in my script and I use `\includegraphics` for it in the same way I am doing for the `textsuperscript` image. But the latter causes a problem.

Comment: @lblb Done! There is the new screenshot. Thanks to you.

Comment: @None The picture file must be into the folder of the your file .tex.

Comment: @Sebastiano  I am sure that my image as `.eps` file is included in the right path. Can the problem be sue to the template type? I use `\documentclass[10pt]{llncs}`

Comment: @Sebastiano the compilation is correct. But when I want to create a pdf file by clicking F10, I get these errors: 
`xx.tex(1): Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected,
xx.tex(1): Package amsmath Warning: Unable to redefine math accent \vec.
xx.tex(1): Font shape `OMS/cmtt/m/n' undefined`

Comment: Finally, I solved it with `\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}` and `\textsuperscript{ \Letter} `. It worked perfectly., Thanks for your help anyways, although for some reason it did not work with me.

Comment: @None Always available :-)

Comment: Is it possible to do the contrary; that is, put a superindex/subindex to a figure?

Comment: @David Ask a new question and include this link. It is not possible to give an answer with another different question.