# index text with a float

Tags: subscripts

I'm trying to write a formula like the following [image]

I need to put little float indexed to the letter L. Please help me.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Do you mean you want to insert an image in a subscript?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I agree with you. But maybe he wants to use a subscript symbol. Also the tag is off-topic.

Comment: That is not a float it it just an image. If you have these small images then `\includegraphics` will work in a subscript just fine.

Comment: I've changed the tag from "indexing" to "subscripts".  In the context of this site, "indexing" refers to the indexes that provide a list of searchable terms in the back of a book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only used my old answer [How to include an image as a superscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427774/how-to-include-an-image-as-a-superscript) ...but in subscript by comment of the user @daleif. Obviously if you want to enlarge or shrink the image, change the scale parameter number.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
$L\textsubscript{\includegraphics[scale=0.04]{example-image-a}}+L\textsubscript{\includegraphics[scale=0.04]{example-image-b}}=z(L\textsubscript{\includegraphics[scale=0.04]{example-image-c}}+L\textsubscript{\includegraphics[scale=0.04]{example-image-b}})$.\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm happy to help you...always to avaliable :-)