# Add superscript to image

Tags: graphics

**Context**

I want to specify my affiliation by the university logo instead of the name, as in "b)" in Figure 1; that is, I want to put the number 1 at the top-left corner of a figure.

This question is related to [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427774/how-to-include-an-image-as-a-superscript/427830?noredirect=1#comment1667887_427830). With respect to that question, I want the inverse result: the logo would be the affiliation, and the superscript text.

**My attempt**

I tried using

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document} 
${}^1$\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image} \end{document}
```

but this code produces "a" (left image) in Figure 1.
[image: Figure 1. a is the result from my code above and b is what I want.]

Comment: texlive does not have a `example-figure.png` ? If I use `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
${}^1$\includegraphics[height=3mm]{example-image}
\end{document}` it [makes this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SeqP.png) which does not look like your image, please clarify the question

Comment: Do you have anything else on the line containing the figure? That is, is it only the figure and the annotations (scripts)?

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FAcm.png) is doable using [`adjustbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox).

Comment: @Werner Only the figure and the annotations.

Comment: `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` ... `{\scriptsize 1} \includegraphics[height=2cm,valing=t]{example-image}`

Comment: @Werner, exactly, the output of your code is "b)" in Figure 1. Thanks.

Comment: @David: So which one are you interested in? All of them, or only `b`?

Comment: @Werner only `b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure I understand your question. Your description is a little confusing. I suggest that you can use some drawing tools to roughly draw the effect you want. I gave an answer, I don't know if it is what you want.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
{\scriptsize 1}\includegraphics[height=2cm,valign=B]{example-image}

{\scriptsize 1}\includegraphics[height=2cm,valign=T]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I will produce a better description and picture, but *this* is what I want.